# How do I look up data from another table?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

In this fictional example, I have two tables; one with employee information and pay rate:

[image: table with employee information and pay rate]

The second with dates and the corresponding number of hours the employee has worked on that day (note that the same employee will likely work more than one date, and have a different number of hours):

[image: table with dates and the corresponding number of hours the employee has worked on that day]

The `Amount Paid` value in the second table needs to be automatically calculated by taking the `Hours Worked` multiplied by the `Wage` for that user.

How can I achieve this in OpenOffice/LibreOffice? (it would be much easier to find this solution if I knew what phrases to search for)

I could hard-code the `Wage` into the second table, but if I want to change the rate for any employee, I would have to go back and modify the wage item every single date that employee worked, and hope I don't fat finger the wage anywhere!

Comment: Not sure what are you asking, are you asking how to auto calculate the `Amount Paid` base on `Hours Worked` and `Wage` ?

Comment: @Bilo Precisely. And the `Wage` value is retrieved from the first table based on the employee's name or other unique id.

Comment: This is something which is really simple using "traditional databases", but I haven't a clue how to implement it in Excelesque programs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simulated environment:

[image]

[image]

The formula I enter in D2 is `=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)*C2`
You may want to learn how `VLOOKUP` works by clicking [[This Link]](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP)